# $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(x^2+9)^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I evaluate the integral using the contour method, in the complex analysis?
I've tried  this many times, but I can't seem to make much progress on it

$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(x^2+9)^2}dx$

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=3y,dx=3dy$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln3}{9(1+y^2)^2}3dy+\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln y}{9(1+y^2)^2}3dy$$

Set $y=\tan t$ in the first integral

For the second $y=1/u$

Comment: This is the usual integral method. But I need to evaluate this integral using complex analysis, by choosing an appropriate contour.

Answer (score 0):

The residue at $3i$ is$$\left.\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln x}{(x+3i)^2}\right|_{x=3i}=\left.\left[\frac{1}{x(x+3i)^2}-\frac{2\ln x}{(x+3i)^3}\right]\right|_{x=3i}=\frac{\ln 3-1}{108i}+\frac{\pi}{216},$$if we define $\ln(3i)$ as $\ln3+\frac{\pi i}{2}$. Alternative definitions only change the real part. The integral is $\pi i$ times the imaginary part of this residue (only half of the usual $2\pi i$, because the infinite-radius quarter-circle with radii on the real and imaginary axes passes through the pole). The result is $\frac{\pi(\ln 3-1)}{108}$, [which Wolfram agrees with](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28ln+x%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B9%29%5E2+from+0+to+infinity).

Comment: But how the contour is taken here? Can you please elaborate.